# Cloned Laravel project over in an EC2 instance, how should I clean up permissions and git?

Tags: linux, git, laravel, amazon-ec2, permissions

I finally have a laravel project configured to work in my Linux EC2 instance, but I don't know much about permissions, and how permissions should be dealt with in Laravel. I have used chmod 777 for too many situations just to get it running, but does anyone have any tips for setting proper file permissions for laravel?

Also I am getting some new .gitignore files that are unstaged

```
On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    app/config/database.php
#   modified:   app/config/queue.php
#   modified:   app/storage/.gitignore
#   modified:   app/storage/cache/.gitignore
#   modified:   app/storage/logs/.gitignore
#   modified:   app/storage/meta/.gitignore
#   modified:   app/storage/sessions/.gitignore
#   modified:   app/storage/views/.gitignore
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#   modified:   app/config/app.php
#   modified:   artisan
#   modified:   public/images/profiles/1300112.jpg
#   modified:   public/images/profiles/1600044.jpg
#   modified:   public/images/profiles/200123.jpg
#   modified:   public/images/profiles/22A00110.jpg
#   modified:   public/images/profiles/23A00003.jpg
#   modified:   public/images/profiles/7A00042.jpg
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   composer.lock
```

How should I go about cleaning out my changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To clean out your changes use this:

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

Permissions should be `755` for folders and `644` for files. 
You can do this by

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

In case, that you are in your app directory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file permissions were set up correctly when they were pushed to github then they will already be stored in git.

You can just run this command if that is indeed the case.

```
sudo git ls-tree -r <branchName> | awk '{print ,}' | cut -c4- | sed s=^=chmod = | bash
```

If you want to see the output before actually running it just delete the '| bash' from the end and run it then.

- sudo  run as root so no permission errors when changing file permissions.
  git ls-tree to get the file permissions and file locations.
- Awk and cut to get only the values you want and remove the leading 3 digits so it works with chmod.
- sed, attach chmod at the start of the output.
  Run the output in bash.

Personally, I believe this should be a native feature in git but it doesn't appear to be and I have no idea why.  Also, if you're using docker you may have to deal with issues using chown and redo the file permissions inside the container because the user inside and outside the container likely have different user id's.